# How to make .html.erb file work outside of Rails?

Tags: html, ruby, erb

I want to create HTML file with Ruby code embedded in it, but Ruby On Rails is too much for my page. I've tried simply giving my file '.html.erb' extension and  embedding ruby like this:

```
<%= 2+3 %>,
```

but it didn't work. I suppose I also have to install 'erb' gem, but where to? How do I make embedded Ruby work without Rails?

Comment: Do you know this http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html  ? :-)

Comment: Or [erubis](https://github.com/guenter/erubis) which is what Rails uses for ERB.

Comment: What environment are you working in? You say you don't have rails - what are you using to serve pages? Sinatra? Jekyll? Some other environment?

Comment: @dpassage, I don't want to use anything besides html with ruby inside of it.

Comment: @lakesare assuming you want people to see those html files on the internet, you're going to need to run some kind of web server with an erb plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your file as

```
#test.html.erb
<%= 2 + 3 %>
```

then

```
#test.rb
require 'erb'

erb = ERB.new(File.open("#{__dir__}/test.html.erb").read)
puts erb.result # => 5
```

Very good documentation is [`ERB::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new). You don't need to install it, as it ships with your Ruby installation. But it is in *standard library*, so you need to require it, when you need it. One more example :-

```
#test.rb
require 'erb'

@fruits = %w(apple orange banana)
erb = ERB.new(File.open("#{__dir__}/test.html.erb").read, 0, '>')
puts erb.result binding
```

and then

```
#test.html.erb
<table>
  <% @fruits.each do |fruit| %>
    <tr> <%= fruit %> </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Lets run the fie :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> ruby test.rb
<table>
      <tr> apple </tr>
      <tr> orange </tr>
      <tr> banana </tr>
  </table>
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby>
```

Comment: thanks, and one more question: how do I start up local server now to execute these files? and will those work on heroku?

Comment: create an config/initializers/myfile.rb, don't know about heroku